# Why python implementation of miller-rabin faster than ruby by a lot?

Tags: performance, python-2.7, ruby-1.9.3

For one of my classes I recently came across both a ruby and a python implementations of using the miller-rabin algorithm to identify the number of primes between 20 and 29000. I am curious why, even though they are seemingly the same implementation, the python code runs so much faster. I have read that python was typically faster than ruby but is this much of a speed difference to be expected?

miller_rabin.rb

```
def miller_rabin(m,k)
  t = (m-1)/2;
  s = 1;  
  while(t%2==0)
    t/=2
    s+=1
  end

  for r in (0...k) 
   b = 0
   b = rand(m) while b==0
   prime = false
   y = (b**t) % m
   if(y ==1)
     prime = true
   end

   for i in (0...s)
      if y == (m-1)
        prime = true
        break
      else
        y = (y*y) % m
      end
   end

   if not prime
     return false
   end
  end
  return true
end

count = 0
for j in (20..29000)
   if(j%2==1 and miller_rabin(j,2))
     count+=1
   end
end
puts count
```

miller_rabin.py:

```
import math
  import random

  def miller_rabin(m, k):
      s=1
      t = (m-1)/2
      while t%2 == 0:
          t /= 2
          s += 1

      for r in range(0,k):
          rand_num = random.randint(1,m-1)
          y = pow(rand_num, t, m)
          prime = False

          if (y == 1):
              prime = True


          for i in range(0,s):
              if (y == m-1):
                  prime = True
                  break
              else:
                  y = (y*y)%m

          if not prime:
              return False

      return True

  count = 0
  for j in range(20,29001):
    if j%2==1 and miller_rabin(j,2):
        count+=1

  print count
```

When I measure the execution time of each using Measure-Command in Windows Powershell, I get the following:

Python 2.7:
Ticks: 4874403
Total Milliseconds: 487.4403

Ruby 1.9.3:
Ticks: 682232430
Total Milliseconds: 68223.243

I would appreciate any insight anyone can give me into why their is such a huge difference

Comment: I'm just profiling the Ruby code to see if that reveals anything.

Comment: Note that you should change `range` to `xrange` in Python 2. `range` unnecessarily *allocates* a list of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these profile results should answer your question:

```
%self     total     self     wait    child    calls   name
96.81     43.05    43.05     0.00     0.00    17651   Fixnum#** 
1.98      0.88     0.88     0.00     0.00    17584   Bignum#% 
0.22     44.43     0.10     0.00    44.33    14490   Object#miller_rabin 
0.11      0.05     0.05     0.00     0.00    32142   <Class::Range>#allocate 
0.11      0.06     0.05     0.00     0.02    17658   Kernel#rand 
0.08     44.47     0.04     0.00    44.43    32142  *Range#each 
0.04      0.02     0.02     0.00     0.00    17658   Kernel#respond_to_missing? 
0.00     44.47     0.00     0.00    44.47        1   Kernel#load 
0.00     44.47     0.00     0.00    44.47        2   Global#[No method] 
0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00        2   IO#write 
0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00        1   Kernel#puts 
0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00        1   IO#puts 
0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00        2   IO#set_encoding 
0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00        1   Fixnum#to_s 
0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00        1   Module#method_added
```

Looks like Ruby's `**` operator is slow as compared to Python.

It looks like `(b**t)` is often too big to fix in a `Fixnum`, so you are using `Bignum` (or arbitrary-precision) arithmetic, which is much slower.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize this was going on under the hood. It definitely clears up some of my confusion

Answer (score 7):

In ruby you are using `(a ** b) % c` to calculate the modulo of exponentiation. In Python, you are using the much more efficient three-element `pow` call whose docstring explicitly states:

> With three arguments, equivalent to `(x**y) % z`, but may be more
>   efficient (e.g. for longs).

Whether you want to count the lack of such built-in operator against ruby is a matter of opinion. On the one hand, if ruby doesn't provide one, you might say that it's that much slower. On the other hand, you're not really testing the same thing algorithmically, so some would say that the comparison is not fair.

A quick googling reveals that [there are implementations](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Ruby) of modulo exponentiation for ruby.

Comment: thanks! This definitely helped clear up some of the confusion for me